# How do I add data in an array within another array in node? I'm using mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

How do I add data in an array within another array in node? I'm using mongoose. My code looks like this. I can create the indexes in the arrays but the data is not inserted:

```
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
  $push: {
    addFoods: {
      food: {
        $each: [{name, measure, addGram, addCho}],
        $position: 0,
      },
    },
  },
});
```